# Complexity and medical constraints vs Open Source Ventilator

Tags: medical-device

This is a question to experts in medical engineering with specialization on lung ventilators.

Let's take a "simpler" design than a full-featured ICU.
We know typically medical devices are complex devices built by high tech companies.

Typically, open source initiatives work on some BMV based appliance.

What could be blocking obstacles, if any, for a typical DIY shop with say mid-range equipment to build such a respirator?

What I have observed so far, there is a list of quite [comprehensive evaluation criteria](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vRl9yZ27KvslftcNvweHgH1A81pO8gHL62TWpY_VY-UELWdK9x-4-3hNw3DbkemClzExPsg8RfnxilP/pub) for open source ventilator initiatives. This introduces more formality to my question.

So far, none of initiatives listed there have got the full score but [they keep improving](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTYAfldxoIiO46VAWH1NlhrwFBn9mguqS2bh1spnLEu4AVVN1cj1vaEm6vOp5Z6UnaAbUwd8dslCXdM/pubhtml).

Is there something crucial missing on that criteria list?

Comment: As you say engineering it is

Comment: @GrahamChiu I am sorry, can't follow your statement, please explain.

Comment: Better asked in https://engineering.stackexchange.com/